# how to add a link to an image using jquery?

Tags: jquery

```
 <li id ="pdf1"> <img id ="pfd1img" src="/Content/img/pdf.png"/>Catalogue</li>
```

script:

```
 $("#pdf1img").attr('href', '/Content/pdf/' + data.pdf1);
```

I'm trying to add a hyperlink to an image. I think I'm nearly there, but am I missing something?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

```
$("#pdf1img").wrap($('<a>',{
   href: '/Content/pdf/' + data.pdf1
}));
```

Try that ^^^

Image elements **cannot** be links, but they can be wrapped in anchor elements which are.

[`.wrap()` in jQuery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

Comment: ahhh du know what i had tried that, i just notice i had misspelt pdf

Comment: No, image elements may not wrap anything at all.

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal thanks for the english correction ^_^ i typed a little too fast i guess

Answer (score 8):

`img` elements do not have `href` attributes. If you want the image to act as a link you have a couple of options. You could [`wrap`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) the `img` in an `a` element:

```
$("#pdf1img").wrap("<a href='/Content/pdf/" + data.pdf1 + "'>");
```

Or you could bind a click event handler to the image and use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location):

```
$("#pdf1img").click(function() {
    window.location.href = "/Content/pdf/" + data.pdf1;
});
```