# Adding link a href to an element using css

Tags: html, css

Can I add an `<a href="">` link to an HTML element using CSS. As I have an image which I want to add a link to a particular page. Can any one help me in doing this?

Comment: Maybe because you already can add content, pictures, and other stuff via ":before" and ":after" to the page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No. Its not possible to add link through css. But you can use jquery

```
$('.case').each(function() {
  var link = $(this).html();
  $(this).contents().wrap('<a href="example.com/script.php?id="></a>');
});
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/r5uWX/1/

Comment: I think [this answer on a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/165146/2636454) provides a better example of this in action.

Comment: It causes console errors in core web vitals.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply add a link using CSS. CSS is used for styling.

You can style your  using CSS.

If you want to give a link dynamically to  then I will advice you to use jQuery or Javascript.

You can accomplish that very easily using jQuery.

I have done a sample for you. You can refer that.

> URL : http://jsfiddle.net/zyk9w/

```
$('#link').attr('href','http://www.google.com');
```

This single line will do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need CSS for this.

```
     <img src="abc"/>
```

now with link:

```
     <a href="#myLink"><img src="abc"/></a>
```

Or with jquery, later on, you can use the wrap property, see these questions answer:

[how to add a link to an image using jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417615/how-to-add-a-link-to-an-image-using-jquery)